# How to convert image path into image on JLabel

Tags: java, jtable

When I select a record from `JTable`, I would like the image of a given path shown in a `JLabel`. When I write code:

```
private void profile_tableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) profile_table.getModel();
    dr_profile_image.setIcon((Icon)model.getValueAt(profile_table.getSelectedRow(),9));
}
```

I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.swing.Icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown because you are casting a `String` to an `Icon`. `DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(int row, int col)` returns the item at row,col as an `Object` and its class type is the class of the instance stored in the table model, in your case a `String`. If this value is a path to the image file that you want to use then you will need to create an `Icon` from that path. You can use `javax.swing.ImageIcon` to do this:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

private void profile_tableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
{
   DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) profile_table.getModel();
   dr_profile_image.setIcon(
      new ImageIcon(model.getValueAt(profile_table.getSelectedRow(),9).toString());
}
```